# Debug header files in C lang with VS Code, Makefile and custom bash-script

Tags: c, bash, makefile, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a `C` program with VS Code that loads in methods through header files and uses a Makefile to compile. I want to place breakpoints in the OTHER `C` files, to see if my methods are working correctly.

**speller.c**

```
#include "dictionary.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
}
```

**dictionary.c**

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
 // BREAKPOINT!
}
```

**Makefile**

```
speller:
    gcc -g -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o speller.o speller.c
    gcc -g -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o dictionary.o dictionary.c
    gcc -g -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -o speller speller.o dictionary.o
```

Here is the custom bash-script I made, so that I can quickly get the newest `.out` files and compiled code and didn't have to re-run all the steps manually.

This was made executable so I could use it in my `tasks.json` later on.

**delete-make-run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f \*.o && rm -f $1 && make && ./$1 $2 $3
```

**launch.json**

```
{
            "name": "gcc build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/speller",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "gcc delete make run",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc delete make run",
            "command": "delete-make-run",
            "args": [
                "speller",
                "texts/aca.txt"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Running my program like this works:

```
$ delete-make-run speller texts/aca.txt
```

When I put a breakpoint in **speller.c** it works, but how do I debug the methods in the `.h` file?

Comment: The methods are not in the header file - that is just the declarations.  Just put the breakpoints in the code you want to debug.  It is not clear why you think the header files are relevant in this.  Try stepping _into_ `load()` from `main()` to start.  You will see that it steps into the function _definition_ in definitions.c. 
Your makefile is unusual - and does no more than a batch file might - for larger projects you will want to take advantage of make's capabilities to only rebuild the components that need rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger works now, when I step **into** load from `speller.c`'s `main` function. Here are the working config files:

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc delete make run",
            "command": "del-make-run",
            "args": [],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/speller",
            "args": [
                "speller",
                "texts/aca.txt"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "gcc delete make run",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```